# fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve UUID but gparted shows the correct UUID

Tags: fsck, gparted, uuid

I'm running CentOS6 on a PowerSpecG211 with a RAID level 1 array (2x2TB) and a couple of SSD's

Yesterday afternoon the partition for /var ran out of space while I was doing some stuff in mysql and the whole system froze.

now when I reboot, I get a couple of

```
fsck.ext3: Unable to resolve 'UUID=....'
```

messages and in the repair shell although mount shows /dev/md127p3 mounted on /var and /dev/md127p5 mounted on /home, doing an ls on those directories shows nothing.

When I boot with a gparted live cd (ver. 0.11.0) I can see the partitions under /dev/mapper/isw_cbfhdhgadc_Volume03 and /dev/mapper/isw_cbfhdhgadc_Volume05, and right-clicking on them and selecting Information shows the exact same UUID's that fsck says it can't resolve.  Also, when I open a terminal window I can successfully mount the partitions and do things with the files (for instance, I did a cp -au /vol3/backup /vol5 and then a rm -rf /vol3/backup).

I have seen other posts where people have problems with mismatched UUID's between their /etc/fstab and the actual device, but in my case, the UUID's match, so I'm not sure what I should do.

I would also like to point out that gparted shows both of the disks in the array as /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc with all of the same partitions, so I am (naively?) assuming this means the array is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information about filesystems and partitions using commands like `dumpe2fs` or `blkid`. With `tune2fs` command you may change filesystems parameters. With `debugfs` you can modify those parameters interactively. They might help you.